# Measuring the distance between two curves with Dynamic time wrapping (DTW) function in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, distance, similarity, curve

To measure the distance between two curves with Dynamic time wrapping (DTW) function  in Tensorflow 2.0, I tried to convert the following DTW python code segment into Tensorflow. But in the 2nd nested loop section, the final_val is not updating into the dtw_matrix. Trying to debug it but couldn't make it yet. What would be a good way to approach this problem?

```
def dtw(s, t):
'''
s,t are 1D vector,eg., 128 by 1
'''
n, m = len(s), len(t)
dtw_matrix = np.zeros((n+1, m+1))
for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(m+1):
        dtw_matrix[i, j] = np.inf
dtw_matrix[0, 0] = 0

for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, m+1):
        cost = abs(s[i-1] - t[j-1])
        # take last min from a square box
        last_min = np.min([dtw_matrix[i-1, j], dtw_matrix[i, j-1], dtw_matrix[i-1, j-1]])
        dtw_matrix[i, j] = cost + last_min
return dtw_matrix
```

I tried the tensorflow implementation in the following way:

```
def dtw(s, t):
n, m = s.shape[0],t.shape[0]

dtw_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n+1, m+1], tf.float32))

for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(m+1):
        dtw_matrix =dtw_matrix[i, j].assign(inf)
dtw_matrix =dtw_matrix[0, 0].assign(0)

for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, m+1):
        
        s_ele = tf.gather(s,i-1)
        
        t_ele = tf.gather(t,j-1)
        
        cost1 = tf.math.subtract(s_ele,t_ele)
        cost  = tf.keras.backend.abs(cost1)
       
        # take last min from a square box
        last_min =tf.math.reduce_min([dtw_matrix[i-1, j], dtw_matrix[i, j-1], dtw_matrix[i-1, j-1]])
       
        final_val=tf.math.add(cost,last_min)
        dtw_matrix=dtw_matrix[i, j].assign(final_val)
return dtw_matrix
```

I suspect it might be due to my tensorflow coding error that I'm not aware of. Also, Is there a way to get rid of these nested loops? It's slowing down the computation.